# :hover in Safari don't "hover-out"

Tags: css, macos, safari, hover

On Safari, the CSS :hover is still active after a child with fixed position is open then closed outside of the parent.

It works again after the mouse are re-entered to the hover zone.

The demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HSC8N/2/ 
Tested on Safari 7.0.1 on MacOS, it should appear on iOS too. It works as expected at least on Chrome 32, Firefox 27, IE9 and IE10.

EDIT: Here's a video of the problem: http://youtu.be/wF_g3OQALqc

```
<div ng-app ng-init="show = false">
    <div class="hover-stuff">

        <div ng-click="show = true">click to open</div>

        <div class="fixed-bg" ng-show="show" ng-click="show = false">click here to close</div>
        <div class="popup" ng-show="show">Great Popup</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.hover-stuff:hover {
    background: red;
    ...
}

.fixed-bg {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}

.popup {
    position: fixed;
    ...
}
```

PS: angular is only here to set `display: none/block` to `.fixed-bg` and `.popup`

Comment: You mean the text "click to open" remains red after a click on "click here to close"? If so, can't duplicate on Safari under Windows.

Comment: I didn't test on Safari under Windows. Here what I have on Mac http://youtu.be/wF_g3OQALqc

Comment: OK, +1 for the nice movie. But I can't help you unfortunately, as I don't have a Mac. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I test this in Chrome 34 and FireFox 28 for Mac and I get that behavior. I'm not sure why this is puzzling, a child is *always* apart of it's parent, so if you hover over the child, you hover over the parent. Why don't you move the popup to a separate div and then you won't have this problem?

Like this:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="show = false">
    <div>
        <div class="hover-stuff" ng-click="show = true">click to open</div>
        <div class="fixed-bg" ng-show="show" ng-click="show = false">click here to close</div>
        <div class="popup" ng-show="show">Great Popup</div>
    </div>
</div>
```